# Model in MVVM for UWP

Tags: xaml, visual-c++, mvvm, uwp

For UWP application there is quite detailed explanation of separation View from ViewModel, using data binding. Many examples show how to `x:bind` in XAML. My questions are about Model. It should run in a separate thread, in-process background task is sufficient for my application.

1. Where should that thread be initiated? `App::OnLaunched()`? `MainPage` constructor?
2. I create instance of ViewModel in `MainPage` constructor and store it in `MainPage`. All other pages have a reference to MainPage, so they access ViewModel. Is MainPage a right space for holding ViewModel object?
3. Then how do Model object and ViewModel object communicate?

A link to a relevant example would work for me.

Comment: Is that how UWP normally works?  Why do you need a separate thread for the Model?

Comment: @RobertHarvey A separate thread for Model needs to allow a job done, receiving data via Wi-Fi in my case. In general, any job unrelated to UI - database processing, numerical calculation etc. - everything that takes time but keeps UI responsive.

Comment: @siarhei You might want to consider having your model in UI thread while it executes its CPU/IO bound operations in a thread pool thread. It also simplifies the communication between UI and the model.

Comment: @MehrzadChehraz That is what I do. There is however a problem now: over time the code expands so that changing any small feature becomes painful. I sit down and draw a block diagram along the VVMM pattern - that is how I want the code to work. Let's do that. Read docs. And then I have questions. I think that separation Model in VVMM pattern, specifically in UWP, is not clearly discussed.

Comment: @siarhei and how having a separate thread for the model make things less painful? it just adds complexity. And yes, there is no standard way of doing what you are asking.